# Can't download cilent generated file in Android Chrome

Tags: android, google-chrome, coffeescript, client-side

Ok, there's a long history behind this one, but the gist is that we need to create and download a little bit of text CLIENT side, into a file called "test.lbl".  Assume we can't access the server side.

The following code (coffeescript) does this by creating a Blob, converting it to a data url, and then clicking the link.  This works GREAT in a desktop Chrome browser.  However, in Android Chrome (not sure what version exactly, but I just installed it as of 3/5/13 from Google App Store) this simply won't work.  In Android Chrome, the file starts to download and then just spins.  (In fact, it shows in your "Ongoing" for quite some time, even after the browser is closed.)

Anyone know why this might not work in Android?  Perhaps a different mime type will make it allow the file to be downloaded?  We're dealing with internal tablets so we can relax any site specific security settings we need to.

Or, is there a better way to go about this entirely?  (client-side generated text file download)

Thanks

```
$("#get-label").on 'click', (e) ->
  e.preventDefault()
  bb = new Blob(['test test test'], {type:'text/plain'})
  evt = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents")
  evt.initEvent("click")
  $("<a>", {download: 'test.lbl', href: webkitURL.createObjectURL(bb)}).get(0).dispatchEvent(evt)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue in Chrome for Android.  I have raised an issue https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=181032 - if you star that you will be able to see all the updates for it.

Comment: Dang.  Thanks for the info.  Voted for it and we'll keep a watch on it!

Comment: It looks like it is getting allocated to an engineers now.